# PHP $_SESSION variable doesn't always increment when called in rapid succession

Tags: php, session, tabs

I ran into a little bug with PHP $_SESSION.  When I open up 12+ tabs all at once in chromium 85 browser on my Ubuntu 20.04, Apache 2.4.41, PHP 7.4.3 local dev server, I noticed that PHP $_SESSION doesn't always increment my tabid variable which I use to give each one of my tabs it's own id.
Say I have the follow page:

```
    session_start();
    if (! isset($_SESSION['tabid'])) $_SESSION['tabid'] = 0;
    ++$_SESSION['tabid'];

    define('TABID', $_SESSION['tabid']);
    echo TABID;
```

When I open this in 12+ tabs I will get something like: 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8 on each respective page.

The expected output on my 12+ tabs would be: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ,11, 12

I've tried tons of things to debug this even trying to increment the session by doing this:

```
    $_SESSION['tabid'] = ($_SESSION['tabid'] *2)+2; 
    $_SESSION['tabid']= $_SESSION['tabid']/2;
```

Just to see if session wasn't registering the simple increment change, but that didn't seem to have a lasting effect.  I've even tested the bug by appending a uniqid() to my output to make sure it was a $_SESSION issue. So changing the last line to:

```
    echo TABID."-".uniqid();
```

would still output something like:

`1-5f5bb8d8a70fa, 1-5f5bb8d8a70fe, 2-5f5bb8d8a70ff, 3-5f5bb8d8a7100, 2-5f5bb8d8a7101, 3-5f5bb8d8a7102, 4-5f5bb8d8a7103, 5-5f5bb8d8a7104, 6-5f5bb8d8a7105, 7-5f5bb8d8a7106, 6-5f5bb8d8a7107, 7-5f5bb8d8a7108`

Which is still the wrong/unexpected behavior.

For the mean time, I will probably use uniqid as my tab ids, but for a few reasons, I would prefer if my tab ids were much shorter.

These are my session settings (they are default ones that came with my install):

```
    Session Support     enabled
    Registered save handlers    files user
    Registered serializer handlers  php_serialize php php_binary
    Directive   Local Value Master Value
    session.auto_start  Off Off
    session.cache_expire    180 180
    session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
    session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
    session.cookie_httponly no value    no value
    session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
    session.cookie_path /   /
    session.cookie_samesite no value    no value
    session.cookie_secure   0   0
    session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
    session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
    session.gc_probability  0   0
    session.lazy_write  On  On
    session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
    session.referer_check   no value    no value
    session.save_handler    files   files
    session.save_path   /var/lib/php/sessions   /var/lib/php/sessions
    session.serialize_handler   php php
    session.sid_bits_per_character  5   5
    session.sid_length  26  26
    session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
    session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
    session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
    session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
    session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
    session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
    session.use_cookies 1   1
    session.use_only_cookies    1   1
    session.use_strict_mode 0   0
    session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

If anyone knows why this is happening, or if you know if this is due to some sort of setting, I'd love to know. Thanks.

Comment: purely curiosity, why do you want to count the number of tabs?

Comment: You can test this more clearly by adding a sleep(10). Basically its a Race condition with php reading the session file, and writing back to it when that script execution finishes. If five php are started at the same time (before any of them finish), then they all read "1" and write "2".